# Why does this system describe the polytope $P$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization, vectors

Let $P = \text{conv.hull}((0,0),(1,2),(2,0))$, where conv.hull denotes the convex hull. Apparently this polytope $P$ is described by the following system:

$$\begin{bmatrix}0 & -1\\-2 & 1\\2 & 1\end{bmatrix}x \leq \begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\4\end{bmatrix}.$$

**Question:** How do you come up with a system that describes a polytope like this? This system equals $-x_2 \leq 0$, $-2x_1 + x_2 \leq 0$, $2x_1 + x_2 \leq 4$, and I'm not sure how I would get there myself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this particular case, all the points are vertices of the polytope $P$.

The line $x_2 = 0$ connects $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$.

The line $-2x_1+x_2 = 0$ connects $(0,0)$ and $(1,2)$.

The line $2x_1+x_2 = 4$ connects $(1,2)$ and $(2,0)$.

Now that we have the surfaces, choose the direction that include the $3$ points.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! However, could you elaborate how you would get to these equations?

Comment: in 2$D$, find the slope and intercept of a line  $y=mx+c$. if they are not a vertical line.